# Where Action Result returned to client will be stored?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, garbage-collection, request, response, actionresult

I have the following scenario in MVC, which causes the IIS worker process to take 3mb space during each postback. I am using ajax request to retrieve data from server for every 5 seconds in mvc. Ajax request will get data from an action method in controller. This is the data returned from controller:

```
return MyObj;
```

MyObj is an action result object which will replace the content of a div element with new data. Using `GC.GetTotalMemory(true);` I found that it returns data close to 3 mb in each post back.

My question is why the action result returned during previous request was not cleared from server memory. My guess is the result of each ajax request is stored in either `Request` or `Response`objects. Where the result returned will be stored ?

Edit:

Thanks to Nom's answer I used `GC.GetTotalMemory(true);` at the begining and ending of the action method to check out the memory used by `MyObj`and found that it uses about only 2 to 3 KB out of 2+ MB of initial memory. This additional 2MB gets added to my worker process memory ( checked with task manager, memory used by the the process increases by 2 to 3 mb on each post back)

So, during each post back (every 5 seconds) this additional 2 MB of data occupies my IIS worker process space. Can anyone explain this behavior to avoid memory consumptions in postback?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [following link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/gc-gettotalmemory). Here is a short explanation:

1. GC.GetTotalMemory returns **approximate** amount of memory thought to be allocated by **all programs**, not just your ASP.Net application.
2. On a web server, this would add allocations from other programs also running in ASP.NET.
3. Your data is not stored anywhere between calls except the case you are storing it explicitly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: At first I thought my result uses 3MB, thanks to your answer I found out that 2 MB was used even before the executing of first line of action method.

Comment: Well, IIS usually reuses threads and corresponding code in order to improve performance. You don't have to worry about additional threads and memory consumption unless your applications are really huge, like dozens or hundreds megabytes each.